# 2;# 5;# Web services returns odd characters

Tags: list, web-services, spservices, ajax

When I use SPServices to query a list it brings back some of the columns with 
odd prefixes and encoded characters.

How can I get rid of the Oddball characters? 
I recognize the @amp; as a HTML encoded character... but what's with this 5;# 
**What is the pattern so I can filter it out?

See results from Chrome List.asmx request: 
 ows_DocType='2;#P&ID'
 ows_Complex='5;#Complex'
etc...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard format used by SharePoint to return lookup values. For example `5;#Complex` means that the item ID is 5 and its Title is Complex.

The same format is also used for multiple lookups. The Web service will return a chain like this:

```
ID1;#Title1;ID2;#Title2;ID3;#Title3
```

Comment: For the record you'll also see # in other column types like calculated columns.

Answer (score 1):

All the columns that have number prefixes are lookup type columns. 
When I look at the Data in JSON

> `<d:DocTypeId m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:DocTypeId>`

My guess is that SharePoint uses that as a reference. 
Since the actual value doesn't exist in that direct table is my guess. 
On my test site the odd prefixes don't show up.

[image]

References:

1. see [Microsoft Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/ebb4b1e1-c414-4f65-aa3b-a339567b032a)
2. see [Blog PeteStilgoe.com](http://www.petestilgoe.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-lookup-columns-in-data-views-using-soap-rest-webservices/)

> Syntax is: “**ID;#Value**”